# Redux вызывает код 2 раза

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Пытаюсь освоить redux в связке с react. Делаю запрос на сервер чтобы сохранить значение в store.
Все работает, но почему-то запрос вызывается дважды. В чем причина?

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

import './css/index.css';
import store from "./redux/_store";

import App from "./_components/App";


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <Provider store={store}>>
          <Router>
              <App/>
          </Router>
      </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import MainContent from "./layout/MainContent";

import {getUser} from "../redux/_actions";

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <MainContent/>
        </div>
    );
};



const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onGetUser: dispatch(getUser())
    };
};

export default connect(
    null,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

**_actions/index.js**

```
import axios from "axios";

import * as types from "./types"

export const getUser = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        axios
            .post("api/user", {})
            .then(res => {
                dispatch(getUserSuccess(res.data.data));
            })
    };
};

const getUserSuccess = userData => ({
    type: types.USER,
    payload: {...userData}
});
```

**_reducers/index.js**

```
import * as types from "../_actions/types";

const initialState = {
    user: null
};


const userReduser = (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case types.USER:
            return {...state, user: types.USER };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default userReducer;
```

**_store/index.js**

```
import {combineReducers, createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

import userReducer from "../_reducers";

const composeEnhancers =
    typeof window === 'object' &&
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ ?
        window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({}) : compose;

const rootReducer = combineReducers({ userReducer });

let store = createStore(rootReducer, composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
));

export default store;
```

Comment: Один из запросов "options" или оба пост?

Comment: @AzizUmarov Оба пост

Comment: Попробуй удалить `<React.StrictMode>`. Я точно уверен, что он 2 раза вызывает render возможно так как `<Provider>` находиться внутри StrictMode по этой причине вызов происходит 2 раза. Это только в dev, в production всё будет норм.